# Where does phonegap fit in inside a laravel project

Tags: laravel, phonegap

Good day everyone. My application has a feature in which I use GPS in my project. And I recently find out that phonegap can help me with that. And that it is really cool since I can use my phone in previewing the application without deploying it on the cloud.

My question is this:

After creating a phonegap app I find out that :

1. There are many folders such as hooks, platforms. etc in the project.

I'm using laravel as my backend since there is an admin panel that would use a computer/laptop.

2. and how can I integrate the two technology. Should I put those folders inside the laravel project. I really don't know what to do. Please help :)

   3. Laravel has blade and phonegap has www where would I put the[image] views.  ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is server side, while PhoneGap is client side. PhoneGap is just a web app exposing JavaScript APIs to your mobile devices functionality, such as camera or address book.

You could create a client application using React, Angular, Vue, etc. to use the PhoneGap API and then make REST calls to your Laravel application.

All your JavaScript should reside within the `resources/assets/js` directory.

Comment: My directory looks like this : 


laravel_project/laravel_directories and the phonegap_project.

Comment: Where would I put the phonegap project ?

Comment: I would place it in `resources/phone-gap/`

Comment: yeah that's a great idea

Comment: My css and js are in my public directory. Should I transfer them inside the phonegap project ?

Comment: I would like to ask if there are any projects of yours that use phonegap in it ? You migh t wanna share your codes and give me your repo ?

Comment: I'd leave them there and add an output path to the phone gap directory in `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Sorry, the repos are proprietary. Nothing open source, it all belongs to clients :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164738/discussion-between-d3cypher-and-btl).